# Can we run SonarQube on a Maven1 project?

Tags: sonarqube, maven-1

We have some old Maven1 project (we cannot upgrade it to the latest maven versions) so I am just trying to understand if there is a way we can run SonarQube on Maven1 version projects..?

If not what is the best alternate to analyze the code quality other than SonarQube?

Answer (score 2):

Modern Maven projects are easy to analyze using the specialized scanner for Maven: it discovers the necessary configuration from Maven's metadata, most notably, the sources, test sources, compiled Java bytecode, and additional information that can improve the quality of the analysis, such as library dependencies.

Without such specialized tool that makes the configuration easy, you can always fall back to the most primitive scanner tool, the [SonarQube Scanner CLI](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli).
Using this tool, you can certainly analyze a Maven1 project, you just have to configure it correctly. This may not be very convenient, but certainly doable. Start with something simple, follow the error messages to get it working, then follow the warnings to get it *working well*.

Comment: Refers to the Sonar Scanner, which is another way, how to analyze the projects (in case of maven maven plugin can be used, for newer version of Maven ofc) - [docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)